# “replace all” and “replace in selector” are grayed out in Pages.app

Tags: mac, macos, pages, text

When using text replacement, “replace all” and “replace in selector” are grayed out and I can’t click on them. How do I get the ability to click on them?

Answer (score 1):

Don't, just do Command-F. If you are trying to do the bigger period trick though, don't bother. It doesn't work anymore.